# VSCode のスニペットをまとめた共有サイトはありますか？

Tags: python, r, vscode

RやPythonを普段使用しているのですが、それらのVSCodeのスニペットをまとめたサイト等ありますでしょうか?
(Githubに上げたりしている人がいたりするのでしょうか？)

目的は以下の2つです。

・自分の周りに書いている人が少ないので有能な方の知見が得たい
・スニペット形式(.json)だとそのまま流用できる

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: これは[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/19110)かもしれません。なぜスニペットを求めてらっしゃるのでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
・自分の周りに書いている人が少ないので有能な方の知見が得たい
・スニペット形式(.json)だとそのまま流用できる
というのが理由です。

Comment: そのあたりの情報を追加するように質問文を推敲していただけると分かりやすくなってありがたいです。質問文を編集するとサイトトップのタイムラインにも上がるので更新された内容を他の方が見てくれやすいです :)

Comment: アドバイス有難うございます！

Comment: [リスト質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1381/3060) のようにも受け取れます。GitHub 含め、まずは検索等で調べてみましたか？仮に有名なサイトがあれば検索でヒットしそうなものですし、一部の人しか知らないレベルなら有用な情報が集まっているのかが疑問です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code用にGoogle検索してMS以外でヒットするのは以下のExtensionくらいでしょうか。
[python-snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cstrap.python-snippets)
他にsnippetsだけでは無いですがこんな記事も。
[10 Visual Studio Code extensions for Python development](https://medium.com/issuehunt/10-visual-studio-code-extensions-for-python-development-de0be51bbeed)

なお、@nekketsuuu さん回答のように、Marketplaceのページでsnippetsとpythonで絞り込むと、現在66個がヒットします。上記Extensionは関連ランクとしては7番目のようですね。
[Search results - python | Visual Studio Code , Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=python&target=VSCode&category=Snippets&sortBy=Relevance)
これらの中から試してみれば良いのでは？

Visual Studio Code用に限定しなければ、以下のように色々とサイトや記事はありそうです。
ただし、有用か？とか信頼できるか？は不明ですが。
[PythonForBeginners](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/)
[Public Snippets - glot.io](https://glot.io/snippets?language=python)
[progrmoiz/python-snippets](https://github.com/progrmoiz/python-snippets)
[satwikkansal/wtfpython](https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython/)
[ReneNyffenegger/about-python](https://github.com/ReneNyffenegger/about-python)

他にはちょっとしたまとめ記事も。
[オレオレPythonコードスニペット集](https://qiita.com/seri/items/8f9ad0fcbf3c02d3d832)
[20 Python Snippets You Should Learn Today](https://medium.com/better-programming/20-python-snippets-you-should-learn-today-8328e26ff124)
[30 Helpful Python Snippets That You Can Learn in 30 Seconds or Less](https://towardsdatascience.com/30-helpful-python-snippets-that-you-can-learn-in-30-seconds-or-less-69bb49204172)
[Python Shortcuts for the Python Beginner](http://www.maxburstein.com/blog/python-shortcuts-for-the-python-beginner/)

Answer (score 1):

「有名なスニペット」という意味では、VS Code Marketplace で配布されている拡張機能に最初からいくつかスニペットが入っていることがあります。たとえば [Microsoft/vscode-python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) には最初から[このような](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/snippets/python.json)スニペットが入っています。Marketplace で検索すると他にもスニペット用の拡張機能が見つかるので、ある意味スニペットが集まっていると言えそうです。